# BC547 doesn't give gain for 100 ms, saturation

Tags: transistors, led, saturation

Why doesn't the BC547 give gain for 100 ms pulse?
Need to drive into saturation? Later use 2n2222 or 2n2219 for 5 leds in parallel in saturation mode. Will it go into saturation at 3 volts.
Should I use a mosfet.

Tested with 1 LED , LED driven at 70 mA ipeak for 100 ms with 10% duty cycle.

When the LED is connected directly to output of the pulse generator (@20 mA, 3 V, 100 ms), it blinks for few ms (may be 100 ms). Light intensity is ok .

Similar intensity is got when the transistor is added, little current gain by the transistor. How to drive it into saturation.

Tried 0 ohm, 470 ohm to 6.8 kohm; base resistors for transistor.

The voltage is 3 V, new AAA cells.
The LED is 5 mm yellow clear transparent.

Later I want to drive 5 LEDs connected in parallel, each LED driven at 70 mA ipeak for 100 ms with 10% duty cycle. Total 350 mA for 100 ms. Will use 2 D cells with these leds.

[image]

Comment: Did you measure current through Led ?

Comment: Maybe transistor or LED or both are now damaged since no resistors were used? Verify them.

Comment: The base-emitter voltage must have a value around 0.6V. Therefore an adequate RB resistor is necessary, otherwise the Vbe takes on the output value of the 74HC74 and the junction breaks, or rather you have already broken it.

Comment: Led has not 100 ms one-shot. The time is limited by a differentiator circuit with an RC = 10^(-8)*100 k = 1 ms ...

Comment: What supplies the 3V to your circuit? If it's something like a coin cell then that's your limiting factor.

Comment: Three DEAD AAA alkaline cells in series produce 3V.

Comment: @HarshitaKapur a 1 ms pulse is more than enough to kill a BJT if you drive enough current into the gate, or an LED if you drive enough current through it (which you will do if there's no resistors involved). Which one died first is a coin toss, but I'd replace both and add resistors.

Comment: No such thing as 100 kpf within SI. Do you mean 100 nF? Prefixes don’t stack in SI.

Comment: The sum of VCE sat and the LED forward voltage is above 3V. No chance with more than 100 mA. Use a MOSFET.

Comment: @winny 100kpf is 100nF

Comment: @Jens will try mosfet , but 3 volts ones are difficult . But Vce sat is 0.7 V , led Vf is 2.2 .

Comment: Engineering top tip: the SI system is in use throughout the world. Please use it. It will make your career much easier when you talk to colleagues and order components.

Answer (score 6):

You are severely overloading (350mA) the low current BC547 that works poorly
above a collector current of 100mA. Then its Vbe and Vce are very high.
With a 1k base resistor from 3V to the 1.25V base, the base current is only 1.25mA
when it needs to be 35mA using a 51 ohms resistor if the battery 3V does not drop.

You are also overloading the small AAA battery.
[image: overloaded BC547]

Comment: (Nice extrapolations, graphs distinctly different from OnSemi's. Name source.)

Comment: @Audioguru should I increase the Vce voltage to 5 to 10 V . Want to drive bc547 into saturation , as a switch , or should I use a mosfet , low voltage mosfets are not easy to find . I will use 2 D cells when 5 leds are connected in parallel .

Comment: @HarshitaKapur Any transistor can be driven into saturation, but in some circumstances you can only do it once and for a very short time :) BC547 is a small signal transistor, not meant for driving heavy loads, and what you have is a heavy load to the poor 547. Even a 2N2222 would be a better choice - same size. You can drive a BC547 into saturation destructively. Or you can drive it non-destructively - if you lower the load below 100mA. You're asking the wrong question. Instead of asking how to do this with 547 (impossible), ask what cheap & popular transistor you should choose instead :)

Comment: @HarshitaKapur And to answer your question: a 2N2222 will survive with those LEDs, but assume the lowest beta when selecting the base resistor. If you insist on using small transistors, you can parallel two 2N2222s with a 1ohm emitter resistor. Super-glue their flat faces together so they're less likely to thermally run away where one transistor will take all the load and underperform or fail.

Comment: Harshita, you have nothing limiting the saturated current so the BC547 and/or the LED will burn out.

Answer (score 2):

Either you got fake transistors, or you're connecting the transistor incorrectly. Most likely you have the collector and emitter swapped. That will yield switching action but very little current gain. The reverse gain is called reverse beta. The saturation voltage is lower in the reverse mode, but the current gain is very low. For some transistors, the reverse current gain is <1. E.g. 2N3904's is about 1/4 IIRC.

Oh, and start with a single LED. Then you'll know whether you got the transistor reversed, or simply four of them is too much for that transistor. Either may be the cause.

Comment: @HarshitaKapur This comes off as unnecessarily aggressive. Telling people "delete your message" is very rude.